# Remote connection on virtual machine (Hyper-V)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, freeze, hyper-v

I have Win 10 running on a VM on Hyper-V, on my server (Windows 10).

I am connecting remotely from the external network to the VM.
But when I close RDP window, I cannot connect again without restarting to VM.

If I try to connect from Hyper-V interface in the server, it's freezing on the login screen. After restart VM , I can connect without any problem.

There was no such problem until 7 days ago. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I ran into the same issue when updating a test PC to the Windows 10 1903 update, have you upgraded it recently to 1903?

Comment: Yes I upgraded it. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not yet, I will update if I find anything :)

Comment: I uninstalled the 1903 update and the problem has solved.  I'll wait for microsoft to solve this problem on 1903 update. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been observed in Windows 10 build 1903. I am having the same problem. More infomation can be found:

https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/138722-after-august-update-hyper-v-win10vm-crashes-when-connecting-via-rdp-2.html

I resolved the issue temporarily by assigning multiple cores to each VM (as opposed to the usual 1 core). Roll on 1909!